# Display post of specific category on page

Tags: php, posts, categories

What's wrong in the code below ? Even after comparing it with pre-existing codes, I don't get the mistake:

```
$args = array('cat' => 367);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if ($arr_posts->have_posts()) {
  while ($arr_posts->have_posts()) {
    $arr_posts->the_post();
  }
} else {
echo "No posts found";
}
```

Result: Nothing appears, not even the "No posts found" message. But the page is displayed without any error message.

Comment: just means that the code finds (at least) one post of that cat 367; but there is nothing to output anything of it in your code. try adding `the_title()` into the loop.

Comment: if what you posted is not the full code of your page template, please do post the FULL code.

Comment: It's all good, the problem was indeed what you and Jacob below said. I simply forgot to add "the_content();" at the end of the while loop, that's all. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your code that outputs anything for each post. That's not what `$arr_posts->the_post();` does. You need to use [template tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-tags/) like [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) and [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) to output those fields:

```
while ($arr_posts->have_posts()) {
    $arr_posts->the_post();

    the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
    the_content();
}
```

Comment: Dayum, so obvious, thanks dude!